# print a single element from an api called dictionary in python

Tags: python, api, dictionary

The api call

```
from rtstock.stock import Stock
stock = Stock('AAPL')
data = stock.get_latest_price()
print(data)
```

yeilds

```
[{'LastTradeTime': '2:54pm', 'LastTradePriceOnly': '119.855'}]
```

I'm trying to print `119.855` with no apostrophes using

```
from rtstock.stock import Stock
stock = Stock('AAPL')
data = stock.get_latest_price()
print(data['LastTradePriceOnly'])
```

and am getting the error message

```
    print(data['LastTradePriceOnly'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!!

Comment: Notice the data you want to retrieve is actually from a dictionary INSIDE A LIST. First retrieve the dict by calling data[0], then get the value you want by calling data[0]['LastTradePriceOnly'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data is a list containing a single dictionary:

```
data = [{'LastTradeTime': '2:54pm', 'LastTradePriceOnly': '119.855'}]

print(data)     # list containing a dictionary
print(data[0])    # the dictionary
print(data[0]['LastTradePriceOnly'])   # 119.855
```

Comment: works great, thank you for the explanation as well :)